# Please explain to me how this method/code is carry out

Tags: java, casting, char

```
//x2ten Method: Convert everything to base 10
public static int x2ten(String s, int base){    
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    int ret = 0;
    //int multiplier = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int cInt = c -'0';
        
        if ('c' >=0 && c <='9'){
            cInt = c -'0';
        }
        else if(c >='A' && c <= 'Z'){
            cInt = c - 'A' +10;
        }       
        ret = ret * base + cInt;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

can someone please explain to me how this code work??? line by ine

> int cInt = c -'0';
>
> cInt = c - 'A' +10;

I specificly don't understand how those line are carry out. What is the affect of " - '0' " or " - 'A' " etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two specific lines that you asked about, i.e.

> ```
> int cInt = c -'0';
> cInt = c - 'A' +10;
> ```

are the only tricky lines in your code. Once you understand what they do, you will be in a good position to understand the whole thing.

Both lines do the conversion of a character that represents a digit to a numeric value of that digit. Hence, character `'0'` is translated to `0`, character `'1'` to `1`, and so on. This is done by subtracting the numeric code of zero from the numeric code of the character. Since numeric codes of digit characters are consecutive in UNICODE, the subtraction yields the required result.

Same goes for the second line, except for digits above ten, which are represented by letters `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, and so on. `'A'` means `10`, `'B'` means `11`, etc. Again, letter codes are consecutive, so subtracting the code for character `'A'` and offsetting by ten (because `'A'` represents the digit of ten) yields the numeric value of the "digit" in bases 11 and above.